# Android: incomplete soap response?

Tags: android

I make a soap request in my Android app using `HttpURLConnection` the response is a base64 encoded string holding the data of an image.

the problem is that the response always received in complete. so the image can not be constructed correctly.

what can be the reason for this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly server is sending the incorrect Content-Length header.

Did you write the server code?

Happened to me once when I was reporting the content length based on the size of buffer not the actual size of data inside buffer.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll check and tell you later

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine blogged about this a year or so ago.  Base64 is supposed to be built in, but isn't/wasn't?  He has details [here](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html).

Comment: He is receiving an incomplete response when data is base64 encoded, not that it can not be decoded.